# How can I Use the while loop until i get 3 rows from a table in mySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to retrieve content content based on their time stamp. And my query is

```
SELECT link,title,timestamp,photo,link,author,comments FROM posts
    WHERE timestamp='*Todays Date -1*' LIMIT 6
```

If the query returns zero rows, how can I query for results 2 days back or three days back using a while statement?

Comment: Please show more of your code and attempted solutions. You can use `num_rows` to check how many rows where retrieved and then alter the query.

Comment: Why does it have to be a `while` loop specifically?

Answer (score 2):

Why not just query full table (without timestamp filter) and return limit of 6 rows.  in this case there would be no reason to iteratatively query

```
SELECT link,title,`timestamp`,photo,link,author,comments
FROM posts
ORDER BY `timestamp` DESC
LIMIT 6
```

This gives you up to 6 records with most recent records returned first.  You should have index on `timestamp` field for this query, which is OK because you should already have one because you were previously trying to filter on this field.

If you have a case where more than 3 rows show up within last day and you don't need to show records from previous days, this is easy enough to achieve by inspecting the values as you loop through the result set.

This also prevents you from getting into an infinite loop if you only have 2 records in the database.

Also note `timestamp` is a reserved word, you should be careful when using such field names. If you have to use a reserved word as field name, you must enclose it with backticks.

Answer (score 0):

maybe a for could work

```
$i=1
for ($row='';$count=0;$i++) {
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT link,title,timestamp,photo,link,author,comments FROM posts WHERE timestamp='*Todays Date -$i *' LIMIT 6");
    $count = mysql_num_rows($result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the query that you want both filters the results and orders them.

```
SELECT link, title, timestamp, photo, link, author, comments
FROM posts
WHERE timestamp <= '*Todays Date -1*'
ORDER BY timestamp desc
LIMIT 6;
```

If you actually want 3 rows and not 6 (as suggested by the post title), then change the `6` to `3`.